# I want the background picture not to be displayed in the IE. How do I do that?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background

Here's the CSS , and I want the background picture not to be displayed in IE . Instead I just want the background color to be displayed. How do I do that?

```
html, body {    
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;    
  background: #a9ac41;
  background-image: url("background.png");    
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;    
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;     
}
```

Comment: you've got `margin` and `padding` specified twice. (that's not going to cause a problem, but won't help anything either)

Comment: the question really is "which IE versions do you want to affect, and why?" If you want to do this for all IE versions, then I'd argue against it. If you're trying to handle the problem with IE8 not supporting `background-size`, then there may be ways around it. But either way the answer will be different according to the IE versions you want it for, so please specify.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that the problem here is `background-size`. IE8 and earlier don't support it, so you're seeing your image messed up in IE8 and you want to solve it by reverting to a plain background.

Firstly, I should tell you that `background-size` is supported in IE9 and later, so you don't need to do this as a blanket change for all IE versions. You only really need to deal with the lack of support in IE8 and earlier.

Here are some options for you:

- **Pure CSS solution:**
  You can take advantage of the way CSS handles unknown properties to provide a pure CSS fallback for browsers that don't support `background-size`, by specifying the size as a parameter in a shorthand `background` style:

  ```
  background: #a9ac41;
  background: url("bgimage.png") cover;
  ```

  IE8 will ignore the second `background` entirely because doesn't understand `cover`. Other browsers will ignore the first one because the second one overrides it. Problem solved: all browsers have a working background.
- **Feature detection solution:**
  You could use a tool like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/) to test for browser support of `background-size`, and then use Javascript to change the page accordingly (eg load a different stylesheet if it is/isn't supported).
- **`filter` solution:**
  Although IE8 doesn't support `background-size`, it is possible to use the `-ms-filter` property to emulate it, with some degree of success. You would use code like this:

  ```
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path_relative_to_the_HTML_file', sizingMethod='scale')";
  ```

  Example [taken from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)
- **Polyfill solution:**
  There are some 'polyfill' scripts available which implement some of the missing CSS features into old IE versions, including `background-size`. In this case, the one I'd recommend is [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/). Follow the instructions on the css3pie site and you'll be able to use standard `background-size` even in very old IE versions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very nice and clean solution..dont know whether OP is interested in reading this all....but a very fruitful answer for future visitors +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

use `conditional` statement.

```
<!--[if IE]>
Place IE specific content.
<![endif]-->
```

If version specific, you can mix the code like this -

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
Place content for IE lower than 8
<![endif]-->
```

created a rough tested code, and checked in IE 9 -

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<style>
html, body {       
  background: #a9ac41;
  background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png");    
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;    
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;     
}
</style>
<![endif]--> 

<html>
<body>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Conditional statements wont work for IE10 so you can manage it via `media queries`.

Example thread  - https://gist.github.com/atk/4025104

Comment: please note that the conditional comments feature is not available in IE10, so this trick will not work in IE10 (or future IE versions).

Comment: @Spudley For IE10 specific case you can run media query then

Comment: well yes, there are ways of detecting IE10 as well. to be honest though, it's better to do feature detection, because there's nothing about IE10 (or even IE9) that would be a problem for the OP's background image. All the answers here offering conditional comments to detect IE are barking up the wrong tree. I guess the OP isn't really asking the right question, but it helps to read between the lines in cases like this and work out what the actual problem is rather than giving the answer that is being asked for.

Comment: @Spudley Actually the OP has not tagged the question with JS/jQuery or any other stuff so have to be in the fixed container..media queries is what I can think off at most..let me know if you know some another way of handling it in html/css constraint..please let me know..will be a g8 learning stuff to me :)

Comment: in my answer, I've given four possible solutions to the problem. Only two of them use Javascript. The first one is a pure CSS solution that uses the background image if `background-size` is supported, so IE8 will get the plain colour background as a fall-back. I suspect this is the best solution for him (it's certainly the cleanest solution), but there are several other ways of solving the problem, some of which will give him a working background image even in old IE versions, without any need for a plain colour fall-back.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional stylesheets are what you need.
By using the code below you can set a stylesheet that is only used in IE, in which you can set an alternative style for the body.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: note that if he wants all IE versions to be affected, then this will fail in IE10, because it doesn't support conditional comments.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! Is there an alternative that does work in IE10?

Comment: Not a direct equivalent -- MS are making a concerted effort to make IE conform to standards, so they're removing non-standard stuff like this. On the flip side, though, it also means that IE10 is generally pretty good at being compatible with your code, so tricks like this are very rarely necessary. Where they are necessary, you should use feature detection (eg use the Modernizr library) rather than browser detection.

Answer (score 1):

replace the tag `html` of your HTML for this:

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

then in the css:

```
    html,body{      
      margin:0;
      padding: 0;

      background-image: url("background.png");

      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover; 

      margin:0;
      padding: 0;     
    }

html.lt-ie9,html.lt-ie9 body{
      background: #a9ac41;
      background-image: none;
}
```

Note: IE10 doesn't support conditional comments son this method works in < IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version(s) of IE you want to target, you can use conditional comments (and/or an IE-only stylesheet):

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Note that this won't work in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of different ways to do this, and it really depends on what else you're doing with the page. One simple way would be the following HTML in the `<head>` tag.

`<!--[if IE]><style>html,body{ background-image: none; }</style><![endif]-->`

Comment: note that if he wants all IE versions to be affected, then this will fail in IE10, because it doesn't support conditional comments.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code in your html.

```
   <!--[if IE]>
    <stye>
      html, body {    
        background-image: none; 
      }
    </style>
   <![endif]-->
```

Comment: note that if he wants all IE versions to be affected, then this will fail in IE10, because it doesn't support conditional comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously multiple ways to answer this question, some good methods already mentioned. Here is another method that I use most often and it requires less bytes:

To target only Internet Explorer, put an "*" in front of the code that you want to target for I.E. Using your example above, for the background to not appear in I.E. use the * like so:

```
    html, body {    
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;    
    background: #a9ac41;
   *background-image: none;  
    background-image: url("background.png");    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;    
    margin:0;
```

If and when it doesn't work, likely your rules are conflicting. In such cases, use "!important", like so:

```
    *background-image: none !important;
```