# Browser Compatibility Issues (IE & Firefox)

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I'm trying to make my website (http://www.arcdna.com) compatible with both Firefox & Internet Explorer. There are two primary concerns that are causing the biggest issues.

1. Parallax Images will not show up.
2. Footer will not show up.

With the parallax images, I used (`background-image:cover;`) as the code to display the image; however, from doing research, I believe this is what causes the issue. I am not sure of an alternative route to fix this problem.

With the footer, i used a simple footer element; however, the links are all unaligned and the background color is missing.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would really help if you'd specified the IE version(s) you're testing with. If the problem is with the lack of support for `background-size` in older IE versions, you can read this answer I gave to a similar question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645343/i-want-the-background-picture-not-to-be-displayed-in-the-ie-how-do-i-do-that/16647265#16647265 -- four different solutions for you there.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to StackOverflow!  In addition to Spudley's comments up there, it would help if you posted a (simplified) version of your site's markup/CSS directly into the question.  Reviewing an entire page's worth of HTML can be daunting, and also doesn't leave a good reciept for future Stackers who may have the same issue as you (once you've fixed the problem on your site, there will be no way to see what the original issue was).

Answer (score 0):

For IE Compatibility you can try this IE6+ 
Method 1 [jquery]

```
<img src="images/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }
```

JQUERY

```
    $(window).load(function() {    

        var theWindow        = $(window),
            $bg              = $("#bg"),
            aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

        function resizeBg() {

            if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
                $bg
                    .removeClass()
                    .addClass('bgheight');
            } else {
                $bg
                    .removeClass()
                    .addClass('bgwidth');
            }

        }

        theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

METHOD - 2 : (CSS) IE8+

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

Hope this could be better alternative for cover. 
for footer, cant get your point.