# CSS Background cover that maintains aspect ratio but will always fill full width and height (and create scrollbars for overflow)

Tags: css, responsive-design

This is a particularly strange request, but the client won't budge.

I've almost got what I need currently with:

```
#main_content, .slide {position: relative; min-width: 1200px;}                                                                                                                                           
.slide_layer {position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0; left: 0; min-width: 1200px; padding-bottom: 18px;}
.slide_layer img { width: 100%; }
```

Problem is, if my browser window is longer than it is wide, I end up with empty space below the image. What the client wants is for the image to fill all available height if there is room and create horizontal scrollbars as needed (rather than crop).

The solution I'm thinking of doing is just detecting browser window and stretching the .slide_layer img to fill height via javascript. But this feels crappy and sloppy. Is there a better way?

To make matters worse, backward compatibility is required back to IE7.

Thanks!

Comment: If the client won't budget then you should have plenty of money to throw at the problem.

Comment: Hahahaha, woops! *budge

Comment: This looks like it will at least extend support to legacy IE: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ . Probably doesn't address aspect ratio problem though. If CSS won't solve the problem, I have no doubt that Javascript can and will.

Comment: If your problem is `background-size` not being supported in old IE versions, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645343/i-want-the-background-picture-not-to-be-displayed-in-the-ie-how-do-i-do-that/16647265#16647265) that I posted to a similar question earlier today. Four possible solutions.

Comment: background-size doesn't solve my problem because, as far as I know, there's no way to make it behave as describe. Essentially, it doesn't ensure that the height is 100% filled without skewing, and it doesn't create scrollbars to ensure that the entire image remains uncropped.

Comment: `background-size: cover;` does do that (have image cover all visible space and maintain aspect ratio), but like previous commenters mentioned: ie support requires additional methods since it's not supported.

Comment: I promise, it doesn't do exactly what I'm detailing. I think you're misunderstanding. To be clear:

there can be no empty space above, below, or to the sides of the image. If the image can't fully fill the height of the space, the div will need to get wider, creating horizontal scrollbars, until the full height is filled. Vice versa for filling the width. 

In short -- a background cover solution that creates scrollbars so the whole area can be filled.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't necessarily help you with the horizontal-overflow request from your client, but you could rebuild your slides to use a background image, instead of an image within it.

You can then use the CSS3 background-size, set to 'cover':

```
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

This means that the background image will stretch out - whilst maintaining the correct dimensions - to fill the parent.  So, unless your slide is exactly the same dimensions as the image, you'll either have a little off the top/bottom, or left/right cut off from view, but it will always stretch to cover the entire background.

This is a CSS3 property, so won't work back to IE7 without a little help.  Fortunately, [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) can help you out there to get support all the way back to those older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: This doesn't work because background-size:cover crops the image instead of creating scrollbars to ensure that the entire image is always visible regardless of size. It also doesn't ensure that the entire height of the page is always filled (thus expanding width to maintain aspect ratio and employing scrollbars to handle overflow).

Comment: Hi John,  you're absolutely correct in that it crops the image (as I mentioned) - that's the limitation of this option, although I got the impression from your question that your client had introduced the horizontal-scroll thing more recently and that it wasn't set in stone?  My mistake!  In order to make it take up the entire height of the page it's just a case of making sure the parent element is the correct dimensions.  There's a JavaScript alternative, I'll post it in a sec.